# Import Error: No module name "generated" found"

Tags: python, add-on, error

My paths should be correct so I am unsure as to why Blender is giving me this error when I try to tick the addon in the menu.

```
Import Error: No module name "generated" found"
```

Here is the addon:https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1ogggrhofHS87gpS8SQLNXJ0-HlLqJeXX?usp=share_link

GitHub link: https://github.com/niftools/blender_niftools_addon/tree/develop (Install the develop branch, not the current release)

Comment: Hello ! Are you operating on Linux ?

Comment: Hello! I am currently operating on Windows 10.